# PyCharm, NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, pycharm

I am working on a library management system project, I keep getting an error that the name 'name' is not defined when I call the program in the last part. Any help would be appreciated, I will post any screenshots or pages if needed. The program will also take the book names I added from a text file titled 'pythonDatabase.txt'

Here is my source code...

```
# library management app

# def of lib class
class Library:
    def __int__(self, bookslist, name):
        self.booksList = bookslist
        self.name = name
        self.lendDict = {}

    # func that shows all books in lib
    def displayBooks(self):
        print(f'Here are the books currently in our library: {self.name}')
        for book in self.booksList:
            print(book)

    # func to add a book to lib
    def addBook(self, book):
        if book in booksList:
            print('Book already exists')
        else:
            self.booksList.append(book)
            bookDatabase = open(databaseName, 'a')
            bookDatabase.write('\n')  # making a new line in db
            bookDatabase.write(book)
            print('Book added')

    # func to lend a book
    def lendBook(self, book, user):
        if book in booksList:
            if book not in self.lendDict.keys():
                self.lendDict.update({book: user})
                print('Book has been taken out. Database updated')
            else:
                print(f'Book is already being used by {self.lendDict[book]}')
        else:
            print('Sorry, this book is not in our library')

    # func to return a book
    def returnBook(self, book):
        if book in self.lendDict.keys():
            self.lendDict.pop(book)
            print('Book returned successfully')
        else:
            print('This book does not exist in the database')


# menu creation
def main():

    while True:
        print(f'Welcome to the {library.name} library.'
              'The options are as follows,')
        choice = "" \
                 "1. Display books " \
                 "2. Lend a book " \
                 "3. Add a book " \
                 "4. Return a book " \
                 ""
        print(choice)

        # conditions for menu
        userInput = input('Press Q to quit and C to continue ')
        if userInput == 'C':
            userChoice = int(input('Select an option to continue '))
            if userChoice == 1:  # display books
                library.displayBooks()

            elif userChoice == 2:  # lend a book
                book = input('Enter the name of the book you want to lend:')
                user = input('Enter the name of the user:')

            elif userChoice == 3:  # add a book
                book = input('Enter the book you want to add:')
                library.addBook(book)

            elif userChoice == 4:  # return a book
                book = input("Enter the book you want to return:")
                library.returnBook(book)

            else:
                print('Please choose a valid option')

        elif userInput == 'Q':
            break

        else:
            print('Please enter a valid option')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    booksList = []
    databaseName = input('Enter the name of the database file with the extension: ')
    bookDatabase = open(databaseName, 'r')
    for book in bookDatabase:
        booksList.append(book)
    library = Library(booksList, name) # Here is the line where the error is specified
    main()
```

I tried to change the directory to source root in PyCharm, and I keep getting that error, I have a feeling that I messed up defining my arguments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the traceback message...
[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsrPc.png)

Update 1: after defining name to 'Mizakson' I get another traceback message saying that Library() takes no arguments.

[Traceback_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoDow.png)

Comment: Post the traceback message so we can see the failing line.

Comment: `library = Library(booksList, name)` what should this `name` be?

Comment: So, `name` has not been defined there. What is suppossed to be in it? It seems like you have a main() function to get name, but you try to use it before you call main()?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @tdelaney, I am trying to define 'name' as the library name, should I edit it to what I want to call my library?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @po.pe, I want to define 'name' as the library name.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not define the `name` variable out of your class.
It should look like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    booksList = []
    databaseName = input('Enter the name of the database file with the extension: ')
    bookDatabase = open(databaseName, 'r')
    for book in bookDatabase:
        booksList.append(book)
    library = Library(booksList, "TYPE NAME HERE")
    main()
```

or this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    booksList = []
    databaseName = input('Enter the name of the database file with the extension: ')
    bookDatabase = open(databaseName, 'r')
    for book in bookDatabase:
        booksList.append(book)
    name = "TYPE NAME HERE"
    library = Library(booksList, name)
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am getting another traceback error saying that Library() takes no arguments, I will update my post and put the second traceback message.